# Why do these two versions of quicksort give drastic differences in number of comparisons made?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have two different implementations of quicksort below. I have verified that oth of these versions of quicksort work in the sense that they will sort any array I give it correctly. If you notice (at least it appears to me), Version #2 is exactly the same as Version #1 when the array size `n` is greater than 8. Therefore, I would expect that when I give both of these functions an array of the same size that is greater than 8, they should make around the same number of component wise comparisons on average, but they do not.

For `n > 8`, both functions use `sort3()` and `partition()` functions. I have listed those below as well to show you how I count the number of component wise comparisons.

I know that `W(n)`, the theoretical worst case number of comparisons for these implementations of quicksort is (n(n+2)/4)+8. Therefore, for an array size `n = 500`, `W(n) = 62758`. For a test run on an array of size `n = 500`, Version #1 makes about 5000 comparisons on average which is reasonable. However, Version #2 is making 80000 comparisons on average. Obviously this can't be right - Version #2 is making more comparisons than the theoretical `W(n)` and it is exactly (at least appears to me) the same algorithm as Version #1.

Do you see an error that I am making in Version #2?

Version #1:

```
void Quicksort_M3(int S[], int low, int hi)
{
    if(low < hi)
    {
        if((low+1) == hi)
        {
            comparisons++;
            if(S[low] > S[hi])
                swap(S[low],S[hi]);
        }
        else
        {
            Sort3(S,low,hi);
            if((low+2)<hi)
            {
                swap(S[low+1],S[(low+hi)/2]);
                int q = partition(S, low+1, hi-1);
                Quicksort_M3(S, low, q-1);
                Quicksort_M3(S, q+1, hi);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Version #2:

```
void Quicksort_Insert_M3(int S[], int n, int low, int hi)
{
    if((hi-low)<=8)
        Insertionsort(S,n);
    else 
    {
        if(low < hi)
        {
            if((low+1) == hi)
            {
                comparisons++;
                if(S[low] > S[hi])
                    swap(S[low],S[hi]);
            }
            else
            {
                Sort3(S,low,hi);
                if((low+2)<hi)
                {
                    swap(S[low+1],S[(low+hi)/2]);
                    int q = partition(S, low+1, hi-1);
                    Quicksort_Insert_M3(S, n, low, q-1);
                    Quicksort_Insert_M3(S, n, q+1, hi);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Partition:

```
int partition(int *S,int l, int u)
{
    int x = S[l];
    int j = l;
    for(int i=l+1; i<=u; i++)
    {
        comparisons++;
        if(S[i] < x)
        {   
            j++;
            swap(S[i],S[j]);
        }

    }
    int p = j;
    swap(S[l],S[p]);
    return p;
}
```

Sort3:

```
int Sort3(int list[], int p, int r)
{
    int median = (p + r) / 2;
    comparisons++;
    if(list[p] <= list[median])
    {
        comparisons++;
        if(list[median]>list[r])
        {
            comparisons++;
            if(list[p]<list[r])
            {
                int temp = list[p];
                list[p] = list[r];
                list[r] = list[median];
                list[median] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                exchange(list,median,r);
            }
        }
        else
            ;

    }
    else
    {
        comparisons++;
        if(list[p] > list[r])
        {
            comparisons++;
            if(list[median] < list[r])
            {
                int temp = list[p];
                list[p] = list[median];
                list[median] = list[r];
                list[r] = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                exchange(list,p,r);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            exchange(list,p,median);
        }

    }


    return list[r];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried in [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or [codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Are you calling `InsertionSort` on the whole array?? I imagine you want to only sort the subarray - something like `InsertionSort(S, low, hi)`. Otherwise you may be calling a *full* insertion sort within *every* partition of size <= 8...

Comment: `InsertionSort` is only called when `(hi-low)<=8`. This never happens when I have an array size of `n = 500` for example. A call to the function would look something like: `Quicksort_Insert_M3(S,500,0,499)`. So, for that call, `low = 0` and `hi = 499`, so `hi-low > 8` and `InsertionSort` isn't called. Right?

Comment: @Zack: No. That's not right at all. Quicksort recursively partitions the array into subarrays. So however large the initial array is, you will end up dealing with small subarrays within the recursive calls.

Comment: You call the function recursively.  You pass down the same n, and a new low and hi that are closer to each other.  Eventually low and high end up within 8 of each other, and you insertion sort the entire array.  There are many calls where this happens.

Comment: Stupid me. I see where I was mistaken there. So, now I'm thinking instead of `InsertionSort(S,n)` it should be `InsertionSort(S,hi+1)`. Yes?

Comment: @Zack No, you need to pass both the upper and lower boundary

Comment: @Sebastian: But `InsertionSort`  only needs to know the number of elements, which would be `hi+1` correct? Why do I need the lower boundary as well? I have tested with `hi+1` - I do get better comparison results, but maybe this isn't quite right.

Comment: @Zack: Suppose you need to sort elements 55 to 60, what good is it to know that there are 5 elements to sort, if you don't know which of these? You need to adjust the signature and implementation of insertionsort to be able to deal with non-zero based lower boundaries.

Comment: `void Insertionsort(int S[], int low, int hi)
{
 if((hi-low)+1>1)
  Insertionsort(S,low,hi);
 Insert(S,hi-low+1);

}`

Would that be how InsertionSort should look? And when I call it: 

`if((hi-low)<=8)
  Insertionsort(S,low,hi);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your error is that when you do the insertion sort you are still using the original size of the array. Therefore you end up doing an insertion sort on the whole array.

Comment: My code never (at least shouldn't) call `InsertionSort` when I pass an array of size `n > 8`. For example, for an array of size `n = 500`, the call to Version #2 would be: `Quicksort_Insert_M3(S,500,0,499)`. So, for that call, `low = 0` and `hi = 499`, so `hi-low > 8` and `InsertionSort` isn't called. Right?

Comment: @Zack but your code is called recursively with smaller sub parts of the array and thus will reach that branch multiple times - just add a breakpoint and you will see!